# Rails - Skip Devise Authentication Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm trying to skip devise authentication for my subscription controller but to no avail.  My registration controller and sessions controller skip_before_filter both work but not the subscriptions controller which I just added recently.  What am I doing wrong?

```
class V1::SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController
skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, if: :json_request?


def create

    @subscription = Subscription.new(subscription_params)

    if @subscription.save 
        render json: @subscription, status: :created
    else
        render json: @subscription.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
end

private

def subscription_params
    params.require(:subscription).permit(:subscription_email)
end
end
```

My application controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include CanCan::ControllerAdditions
  include ActionController::RespondWith
  include ActionController::Serialization

  acts_as_token_authentication_handler_for User

  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render nothing: true, status: :forbidden }

    end
  end
end
```

And my routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

devise_for :users, skip: [:sessions, :registrations, :passwords]

  api_version(module: "V1", header: { name: "Accept", value: "application/vnd.rolotext.json; version=1" }) do
    devise_scope :user do
      post 'registrations' => 'registrations#create'


      post 'sessions' => 'sessions#create'
      delete 'sessions' => 'sessions#destroy'

      post 'passwords' => 'passwords#create'
      patch 'passwords' => 'passwords#update'
      post   'passwords/check_email' => 'passwords#check_email'
    end

    get '/me' => "users#me"
    patch '/me' => 'users#update'
    delete '/me' => 'users#destroy'


    resources :cards, except: [ :new, :edit]
    patch '/logos' => 'logos#update'
    resources :logos, except: [ :new, :edit, :destroy ]
    resources :uploads
    post '/subscriptions' => "subscriptions#create"

  end
end
```

Any help would be mucho appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I'm usually adding this in my user controller if I want to exclude some pages from auth:

`before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:sessions, :registrations, :passwords]`

It should exclude auth for pages in except..
Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried that and unfortunately it doesn't work.  As I mentioned earlier too, the other controllers have no issue with skipping authentication and they're not listed as an exception in the authenticate_user! before filter.

Comment: One last think what I'm thinking about to try to add that exception into application controller..